# What is the purpose of =+ in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, credit-card, logical-operators

I saw something 
`digit = +digit;` in [jQuery Credit Card Validator](https://github.com/PawelDecowski/jquery-creditcardvalidator/blob/master/jquery.creditCardValidator.js) @line 127

What is the purpose of this usage.

Comment: In case digit is a string, this will parse to number

Comment: The `+` just casts `digit` to a number.

Comment: @juvian not an `int`, a number; JavaScript doesn't really have an integer type.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker not really. It works with floating point representations and even with parseFloat you would have many differences.

Comment: And as long as we're being pedantic, it's not a *cast*, it's a *conversion* (@j08691).

Comment: `+digit` is JS hack to turn string into a digit, it's like `digit >> 0` to floor (round `Math.floor`) the number.

Comment: It is a little bit different from parseInt() because it converts string to a number as @t-j-crowder said already. It converts null to zero